# I'm getting an Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'ID' of null. Only when trying to access the last two items of an Object

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-apps-script

**Edit**

So I figured out it has something to do with the value of one of the items in the object.

Date Introduced: "2020-01-01T00:00:00.000Z" - No bueno

Date Introduced: "01/01/2020" - Muy bien

It was the only difference and works now that it has been changed. Does anyone know why this might be?

**Background Info:**

I have a web app with 3 buttons. Depending on the button you press it changes the status of a row with a matching ID on a google sheet. After each button click it then updates #output (just a div that I can place some text in) with the new status.

```
 $(function(){
      var object = randomControllerID()
      
      var text = 'You have controller with ID: ' + object.ID + '<br>Currently the status is: '+ object.Working
      $('#output').html(text)
      
      $('#Yes').click(function(){
      google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(onSuccess).sheetUpdate(object.rowNumber,3,this.id)
      })
      $('#No').click(function(){
      google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(onSuccess).sheetUpdate(object.rowNumber,3,this.id)
      })
      $('#Dead').click(function(){
      google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(onSuccess).sheetUpdate(object.rowNumber,3,this.id)
      })
    })
    function onSuccess(data) {
        console.log(data)
            var text = 'You have controller with ID: ' + data.ID + '<br>You changed the status to: '+ data.Working
            $('#output').html(text)
        }
```

**Problem:**

The google sheet update works for everything however, the onSuccess function returns null and doesn't update #output if the ID is equal to either of the last two rows on the spreadsheet. I have no idea why. The error I get when ID is equal to either of the two last items is:
[Cannot read property 'ID' of null](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vw4oU.png)

If in the .gs I hardcode controller as either of the two last rows in the spreadsheet, data comes back as an object with ID as one of the keys. So I'm not sure why it would pass correctly for every other value except the last two rows.

```
function sheetUpdate(controller,column,value) {
  
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById('X')
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Controllers");
  var range = sheet.getDataRange();
  var values = range.getValues();
  values[controller][column] = value
  range.setValues(values)
  
  var data = getControllerData(values[controller][0])
  Logger.log(data[0])
  return data[0]
}

//pass in controller ID and get back all details as an object
function getControllerData(controllerID){
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById('X')
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName('Controllers')
  var range = sheet.getDataRange()
  var values = range.getValues()
  var obj = {}
  var result = []
  var headers = values[0]
  var cols = headers.length
  var row = []
  for (var i = 1; i < values.length; i++){
    row = values[i];
    obj = {};
    for (var col = 0; col < cols; col++){
      obj[headers[col]] = row[col];    
    }
    result.push(obj);  
  }
  
  var object = result.filter(function(item) {
  if(item.ID === controllerID) {
    return item
    }
  })
  
return object
}
```

Comment: Could it be a formatting issue? I.e. that the spreadsheet formats the last two rows as a different value?

Comment: Yeah for sure, without a doubt has something to do with passing over a timestamp with "2020-01-01T00:00:00.000Z" format.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Dates get converted to objects

If you have a value in a cell that is formatted as a date, getting the value from the sheet will result in a date **object**. Doesn't matter exactly what format it shows up in in the sheet, it will always be a date object once it gets to the Apps Script.

For example with this data:

[image]

With this script:

```js
function dateTests() {
  file = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  sheet = file.getSheetByName("Sheet1");
  range = sheet.getDataRange();
  values = range.getValues();
  
  console.log(values[0][0])
  console.log(JSON.stringify(values[0][0]))
}
```

```
// OUTPUT

Tue May 05 2020 00:00:00 GMT+0200 (Central European Summer Time)
"2020-05-04T22:00:00.000Z"
```

Which is what a Date object looks like.

The advantage is that you have all the [methods of the JavaScript Date object](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_date_methods.asp) available to you.

If you *don't* want this to be an object then make sure to select all the column and go to `Format > Number > Plain Text` in the UI. Be careful though because Sheets will try to auto-detect formats, and if it recognises a date, it may convert it to that format.

To make your code really robust, you can even do something like this to check if its a date object:

```
if (date instanceof Date) {
  // Treat as object
} else {
  // Treat as string
}
```

So whether you are copying from or to your sheet, you can coerce your data into the right format for you.